# Which local port is used for http or ssh protocol?

Tags: http, ssh, network-protocols

When we use web brower to use `google`, we type `www.google.com` in the web brower. I know it equals to `www.google.com:80` because the default port number is `80` in http protocol.

When we use `ssh` to connect our local PC to remote server, we use `ssh user@remote`, which equals to `ssh user@remote -p 22` because the default port number is `22` in `ssh` protocol.

My first question is:
Are the default port number `80` in http or `22` in ssh **local** port or **remote** port?

I guess the answer is: remote port. Because if we use severl `ssh` commands to connect our local PC to several different remote servers, the default port are always `22`. If we use several web browers to google something, the default port number are always `80`.

My second question is:
If we use severl `ssh` commands to connect our local PC to several different remote servers, what is the `local port number` for different `ssh` sessions? If we use severl web browers to connect our local PC to `www.google.com`, what is the `local port number` for different web browers?

Comment: The local port is usually chosen randomly by the OS for each connection.  A command like Unix's `netstat` can show you what is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

22 is about the remote port only.

You cannot specify a local port for an SSH connection, but as [detailed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526751/7490), you can use [`nc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) (or netcat) utility in order to act as a proxy:

```
ssh -p 33101 -o 'ProxyCommand nc -p 33101 %h %p' $SERVER_2
```

The `-o` parameter allows ssh to set the `ProxyCommand` option, that is: the command to use to connect to the server ( '`%h`' will be substituted by the host name to connect and '`%p`' by the port).

For HTTP connection, you could [specify a local port directly using curl](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-connections#local-port-number)

> The local port number is usually randomly assigned to your TCP connection by the network stack and you normally do not have to think about it much further.
>
> Ask curl to use a local port number between 4000 and 4200 when getting this HTTPS page:
>
> ```
> curl --local-port 4000-4200 https://example.com/
> ```

Comment: Can you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545577/are-communication-protocol-half-duplex-or-full-duplex)