# Are communication protocol Half-duplex or Full-duplex?

Tags: http, ssh, network-protocols

I know there are a lot of different `comminucation protocals` like: `http, tcp, ssh, socks5, SMTP, POP,`etc.

I also know that to achieve a comminication, we need to connect `localhost:localport` to `remotehost:remoteport`. For example, if we google something, we would connect a random local `port` to `www.google.com: 80`. If we `ssh` a remote host, we would connect a random local `port` to `remotehost: 22`.

My question is: Are communication protocol **Half-duplex** or **Full-duplex**?

I guess the answer is `Half-duplex`. Because I think in `http` connection, at first we send the request from `localhost:localport` to `remotehost:80`, and then the remote server send its response from `remotehost:80` to `localhost:localport`. Similarly, in `ssh` connection, at first we sent the `ssh` commands to remote host, after receiving the commands, the remote host do something and send the results back to the local host.

So I think in one connection between `localhost:localport` and `remotehost:remoteport`, the message is sent either from `localhost:localport` to `remotehost:remoteport`, or from `remotehost:remoteport` to `localhost:localport`.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/mule-shell-ssh-connector):

> SSH is a bidirectional full duplex protocol, which means that it’s not synchronous like HTTP where you need to send a message for a response to happen.
> With SSH the remote host might want to tell you something even if you have remained silent. This connector uses a callback flow approach to decouple the “sending” operation from the “receiving” operation.

As documented [in this IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zhu-http-fullduplex-08), most implementations do allow full-duplex HTTP (for 2xx responses).

> Full-duplex HTTP follows the basic HTTP request-response semantics but also allows the server to send response body to the client at the same time when the client is transmitting request body to the server.
>
> Requirements for full-duplex HTTP are under-specified in the existing HTTP (Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1) specification, and this memo intends to clarify the requirements of full-duplex HTTP on top of the basic HTTP protocol semantics.